# Why is rvm changing paths without an rvmrc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, bundler

Today I ran again into the dreaded `ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run gem install bundler first.` error with bundler. There are plenty of questions on here about it and plenty of tricks for debugging, but I started digging a little deeper, and what's strange is that even when I remove `.rvmrc` and `bin` and `.bundle` I get different results with two different projects. As near as I can tell they should be the same in the eyes of rvm, but I get different results. In two fresh bash windows, Linux Mint:

```
~ $ cd ${PROJECT_PATH}/project1
project1 $ echo $PATH
/usr/local/heroku/bin:/home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin:/home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/bin:/home/fletch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin:/home/fletch/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
project1 $ tree -L 1 -a
.
|-- app
|-- config
|-- config.ru
|-- db
|-- Gemfile
|-- Gemfile.lock
|-- .git
|-- .gitignore
|-- Guardfile
|-- lib
|-- log
|-- Procfile
|-- public
|-- Rakefile
|-- .rspec
|-- script
|-- spec
|-- tmp
`-- vendor

11 directories, 15 files
```

This is the desired output. Now for the other project:

```
~ $ cd ${PROJECT_PATH}/project2
project2 $ echo $PATH
/home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin:/home/fletch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin:/home/fletch/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
project2 $ tree -L 1 -a
.
|-- app
|-- config
|-- config.ru
|-- coverage
|-- db
|-- Gemfile
|-- Gemfile.lock
|-- .git
|-- .gitignore
|-- Guardfile
|-- lib
|-- log
|-- public
|-- Rakefile
|-- README.md
|-- .rspec
|-- script
|-- spec
|-- tmp
`-- vendor

12 directories, 8 files
```

Why are my paths turning out differently? The second one doesn't load the global gemset and also moves the heroku bit further back for some reason. For reference, my default path matches the first one, when I open a fresh console. Is rvm keeping some information in memory or some global file about which projects use which versions? I haven't been able to discern any pattern across my projects. Some work, some don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RVM supports more then just `.rvmrc` one of this files is `Gemfile` with either the `bundler` directive to specify ruby:

```
ruby='1.9.3'
```

or a comment which has preference and is RVM specific:

```
#ruby=1.9.3-p385
```

Comment: Ah, mystery solved. So I gather it reads the `ruby '1.9.3'` line, too, since that's the only thing I've got in my Gemfile. What's the best route to go here? a) install the bundler gem for that version of ruby, b) somehow disable this feature so that the global gemset also gets loaded, c) add an rvmrc, d) ...?